# SQL - how to query for rows based on param and joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following GET endpoint in a Ruby project:

`/endpoint/:special_param`

I have a db with 2 tables. Table 1 contains these columns: `id, special_param_column, joinable_column`

Table 2 contains these columns: `id, joinable_column, other_data`

This is the code I have in the db model to handle the request:

```
def self.some_function(special_param)
  data = find_by_sql(["SELECT ..."])

  return data
end
```

What should I write inside of `find_by_sql` to select all rows in Table 2 which have the same `joinable_column` value as the rows in Table 1 which have `special_param_column` value equal to the `special_param` passed into the function?

For example, let's say the tables contain this data:

```
Table 1
id | special_param_column | joinable_column
===========================================
1    208                    Keanu Reeves
2    349                    Jack Black
...

Table 2
id | other_data | joinable_column
=================================
1    24           Keanu Reeves
2    68           Jack Black
3    11           Jack Black
4    0            Keanu Reeves
...
```

If `special_param = 208`, I want to return rows 1 and 4 from Table 2

Comment: Can you give an example using an input example and the expected output?

Comment: @SebastianP. I added an example

Comment: You should not write anything in `find_by_sql` there are umpteen better ways in rails to query this information but for starters a basic [Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) will solve this for you

Comment: @engineersmnky What would you suggest as a better method?

Comment: @JBrown you tagged this [tag:ruby-on-rails] so I am assuming this is Ruby on Rails ("Rails") (especially given `find_by_sql` is a Rails Method). Rails uses `ActiveRecord` as an ORM. This library allows you to create objects (classes) that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and associate them to one another for convenience when querying data. Please see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: The example makes sense, and it'd be easy to give an answer using pure SQL to join both tables, but do you have any sort of relationship between both tables in your application (models)?

Comment: @SebastianP. yes. Table 2 data `belongs_to :table1` and table 1 `has_many :table2`

Comment: @JBrown does this join happen to be through `joinable_column`? If so then all you need is `Table2.joins(:table1).where(table1s: {special_param_column: 208})`. Simple as that. If the join is not on that column you can create one for this need `t1 = Table1.arel_table; Table2.join(t1.create_join(t1,t1.create_on(t1[:joinable_column].eq(Table2.arel_table[:joinable_column])))).where(table1s: {special_param_column: 208})` <- same result.

Comment: @engineersmnky this didn't work exactly but I was able to piece together the correct SQL string from the error log. I appreciate the help! I will be learning rails more thoroughly in the future but I'm assigned a project at work right now where it doesn't make much sense to do a deep dive. I'm a frontend dev and the longer I go on the more I realize I need to hone my backend skills. Ah well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (* or whatever you want to return) from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.joinable_column = t1.joinable_column
WHERE t1.special_param_column = special_param
```